# Recover accidentally deleted texts on Samsung Galaxy S21

Tags: samsung, sms, data-recovery

I accidentally deleted all my text messages on my Samsung Galaxy S21 FE.
I tried to find them in the cloud. The trash, but to no avail.

Is it possible to retrieve them?

Answer (score 0):

No, if you deleted them from your device, and they are not backed up in any way, you can not get them back.